# Django filter to include all tags for which a certain type of item exists

Tags: mysql, django, filter, django-taggit

I'm using django-taggit.  I am tagging action items and info items.  I want to list all tags for which there is an info item.  I originally wrote:

```
Tag.objects.filter(info_item__name__isnull=False).annotate(info_item_count=Count('info_item'))
```

But this is returning some action items.  How might I rewrite the query so that the Tags are filtered such that there is an info item attached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your info_item model is InfoItem, then try

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType  
Tag.objects.filter(
    taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(InfoItem), 
    info_item__name__isnull=False).annotate(info_item_count=Count('info_item'))
```